# 1555 DXT1 decompression giving incorrect image output

Tags: c++, image, textures, compression

I am trying, in C++, to decompress 1555 DXT1 textures into RGBA 8888, storing the output into a std::string.

I have successfully decompressed 565 DXT1 to RGBA 8888 using the squish lib, but just can't seem to get 1555 working.

The program isn't crashing, and the output image looks almost correct, but there are several pixels in random places that are strange colours, as you can see in the output image below.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
using namespace std;

string              CTexture::extractRGBAData(void)
{
    string strPixels;
    strPixels.resize(m_usImageSize[0] * m_usImageSize[1] * 4);
    for (unsigned long i = 0, j = m_usImageSize[0] * m_usImageSize[1] * 4; i < j; i++)
    {
        strPixels[i] = 0;
    }

    if (m_strImageData.length() == 0)
    {
        return strPixels;
    }

    unsigned long uiDXTCompressionType;
    if (m_uiPlatformId == 8) // GTA III, VC
    {
        uiDXTCompressionType = m_ucDXTCompressionType;
    }
    else if (m_uiPlatformId == 9) // SA
    {
        //uiDXTCompressionType = m_uiAlpha;
        uiDXTCompressionType = m_ucDXTCompressionType;
    }
    else if (m_uiPlatformId == 5) // XBOX, Android
    {
        uiDXTCompressionType = m_uiAlpha;
    }

    if (uiDXTCompressionType == DXT1)
    {
        unsigned long uiWidth = m_usImageSize[0];
        unsigned long uiHeight = m_usImageSize[1];

        if (m_uiRasterFormat == FORMAT_1555)
        {
            unsigned long
                uiPixelKey = 0,
                uiTexelSeek = 0;
            for (unsigned long y = 0; y < uiHeight; y += 4)
            {
                for (unsigned long x = 0; x < uiWidth; x += 4)
                {
                    string strTexel = m_strImageData.substr(uiTexelSeek, 8);

                    unsigned char *pPixels = new unsigned char[16 * 4];
                    unsigned char *pBlock = new unsigned char[8];
                    memcpy(pBlock, strTexel.c_str(), 8);

                    decompress_DXT1_1555(pPixels, pBlock);

                    for (unsigned long yOffset = 0; yOffset < 4; yOffset++)
                    {
                        for (unsigned long xOffset = 0; xOffset < 4; xOffset++)
                        {
                            unsigned long uiPixelKey = (y * uiWidth) + x + (yOffset * uiWidth) + xOffset;
                            //CDebugger::log("uiPixelKey: " + CStringUtility::toString(uiPixelKey) + ", x: " + CStringUtility::toString(x) + ", y: " + CStringUtility::toString(y) + ", xOffset: " + CStringUtility::toString(xOffset) + ", yOffset: " + CStringUtility::toString(yOffset));
                            uiPixelKey *= 4;

                            if (uiPixelKey < strPixels.size()) // this checks if the height has a remainder when dividing by 4 (as the iteration does 4x4 block of pixels)
                            {
                                strPixels[uiPixelKey + 0] = pPixels[(((yOffset * 4) + xOffset) * 4) + 2] & 0xFF;
                                strPixels[uiPixelKey + 1] = pPixels[(((yOffset * 4) + xOffset) * 4) + 1] & 0xFF;
                                strPixels[uiPixelKey + 2] = pPixels[(((yOffset * 4) + xOffset) * 4) + 0] & 0xFF;
                                strPixels[uiPixelKey + 3] = 255;// pPixels[(((yOffset * 4) + xOffset) * 4) + 3] & 0xFF;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    delete[] pPixels;
                    delete[] pBlock;
                    uiTexelSeek += 8;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

void            CTexture::decompress_DXT1_1555(unsigned char *pixels, unsigned char *block)
{
    string strArea = string((char*)block, 8);
    string strPaletteStr = strArea.substr(0, 4);
    unsigned long uiIndexes = CStringUtility::unpackULong(strArea.substr(4, 4), false);
    unsigned char ucPalette[4][4];
    double fPalette[4][4];

    unsigned short usPaletteInt[2];
    usPaletteInt[0] = CStringUtility::unpackUShort(strPaletteStr.substr(0, 2), false); // 1555
    usPaletteInt[1] = CStringUtility::unpackUShort(strPaletteStr.substr(2, 2), false); // 1555

    // based on: http://www.glassechidna.com.au/2009/devblogs/s3tc-dxt1dxt5-texture-decompression/
    float red, green, blue, alpha;

    alpha = (usPaletteInt[0] >> 15) & 1;

    red = ((float)((usPaletteInt[0] >> 10) & 0x1F) * 255.0 + 16.0);
    red = ((red / 32.0) + red) / 32.0;

    green = ((float)((usPaletteInt[0] >> 5) & 0x1F) * 255.0 + 16.0);
    green = ((green / 32.0) + green) / 32.0;

    blue = ((float)(usPaletteInt[0] & 0x1F)) * 255.0 + 16.0;
    blue = ((blue / 32.0) + blue) / 32.0;

    fPalette[0][0] = red;
    fPalette[0][1] = green;
    fPalette[0][2] = blue;
    fPalette[0][3] = alpha;

    alpha = (usPaletteInt[1] >> 15) & 1;

    red = ((float)((usPaletteInt[1] >> 10) & 0x1F) * 255.0 + 16.0);
    red = ((red / 32.0) + red) / 32.0;

    green = ((float)((usPaletteInt[1] >> 5) & 0x1F) * 255.0 + 16.0);
    green = ((green / 32.0) + green) / 32.0;

    blue = ((float)(usPaletteInt[1] & 0x1F)) * 255.0 + 16.0;
    blue = ((blue / 32.0) + blue) / 32.0;

    fPalette[1][0] = red;
    fPalette[1][1] = green;
    fPalette[1][2] = blue;
    fPalette[1][3] = alpha;

    // fetch other 2 colours in palette, interpolated between min/max colours
    if (usPaletteInt[0] > usPaletteInt[1])
    {
        fPalette[2][0] = (2.0 * fPalette[0][0] + fPalette[1][0]) / 3.0;
        fPalette[2][1] = (2.0 * fPalette[0][1] + fPalette[1][1]) / 3.0;
        fPalette[2][2] = (2.0 * fPalette[0][2] + fPalette[1][2]) / 3.0;
        fPalette[2][3] = 255;

        fPalette[3][0] = (fPalette[0][0] + 2.0 * fPalette[1][0]) / 3.0;
        fPalette[3][1] = (fPalette[0][1] + 2.0 * fPalette[1][1]) / 3.0;
        fPalette[3][2] = (fPalette[0][2] + 2.0 * fPalette[1][2]) / 3.0;
        fPalette[3][3] = 255;
    }
    else
    {
        fPalette[2][0] = (fPalette[0][0] + fPalette[1][0]) / 2.0;
        fPalette[2][1] = (fPalette[0][1] + fPalette[1][1]) / 2.0;
        fPalette[2][2] = (fPalette[0][2] + fPalette[1][2]) / 2.0;
        fPalette[2][3] = 255;

        fPalette[3][0] = 0;
        fPalette[3][1] = 0;
        fPalette[3][2] = 0;
        fPalette[3][3] = 255; // transparent black
    }

    for (unsigned long i5 = 0; i5 < 4; i5++)
    {
        ucPalette[i5][0] = fPalette[i5][0];
        ucPalette[i5][1] = fPalette[i5][1];
        ucPalette[i5][2] = fPalette[i5][2];
        ucPalette[i5][3] = fPalette[i5][3];
    }

    for (unsigned long i2 = 0; i2<16; i2++)
    {
        unsigned char index = (uiIndexes >> (i2 * 2)) & 3;
        unsigned char colour[4];
        colour[0] = ((unsigned char)ucPalette[index][0]) & 0xFF;
        colour[1] = ((unsigned char)ucPalette[index][1]) & 0xFF;
        colour[2] = ((unsigned char)ucPalette[index][2]) & 0xFF;
        colour[3] = ((unsigned char)ucPalette[index][3]) & 0xFF;

        // store colour
        pixels[(i2 * 4) + 0] = colour[0] & 0xFF;
        pixels[(i2 * 4) + 1] = colour[1] & 0xFF;
        pixels[(i2 * 4) + 2] = colour[2] & 0xFF;
        pixels[(i2 * 4) + 3] = colour[3] & 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion -- repeatedly calling the allocator in the loop will slow down your program, and it is even worse that it is a doubly-nested loop.   Just call `new[]` and `delete[]` only once outside of those loops.

Comment: Okay thanks, but my goal is to get the correct image output before looking at optimization improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how DXT1 works a bit.

There isn't any alpha in the 2 base colors. They're both in 5:6:5.

The "alpha" is only coming from the case where `c0 <= c1`. If the block fits this condition, then any pixel with the index 3 will be fully transparent (the 1 bit of alpha is inferred from that).

So... read `5:6:5` (and set alpha=255 for those) instead of `1:5:5:5` in the base colors, and change your alpha on the "transparent black" case from `0,0,0,255` to `0,0,0,0` (actually transparent black instead of opaque black), and you should get better results.

Comment: Oh wow it works, thanks a lot! I ran the file through the 565 decompression code that I already have and it works fine. Bad documentation I was looking at. So I guess raster format 1555 simply isn't used in DXT 1 right? Also where is raster format 1555 used then?

Comment: 1555 isn't directly used, no. You can argue the decompressed data is in a format that's better than 1:5:5:5, but it's not a direct thing.

Comment: I'd missed the second part of your question. 1:5:5:5 is (was?) used as a render-target format sometimes (some displays did use that format).